# Assign Accessibility access to an application through code

Tags: objective-c, macos, applescript

Can we assign Accessibility access to an application through code ?

As on 10.12.5 now , there is SIP feature which restricted to access to TCC.db file. So Is there any other way ?

Comment: No. I don't want to disable SIP. But can I give accessibility access to an application using through AppleScript or using some other code ? Actually I want to install the safari extension automatically.

Comment: I want to click the Trust button while installing extension using AppleScript. But due to SIP feature I am not able to update TCC.db file to give access of Trust button to my application.

Comment: @CJK, I believe Yogesh Arora is referring to the  `/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db` database that holds the necessary and related settings shown under System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility. There used to be a way via SQL to mod the TCC.db database so one didn't have to go through the GUI however, it's now protected by SIP.

Comment: Yes. It's now protected by SIP so not able to insert a row in it. 
So Is there any way ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know, but I don't believe it's possible through AppleScript.

Comment: Are you sure it's protected by SIP? I do not see any attributes on the file that would lead me to believe it is.

Comment: Yes. Its protected by SIP as when I disabled the SIP then able to insert.